# Querying nodes based on relationships between two different nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with two different types of nodes A and B connected by a relationship rel. It exists such that there may be multiple nodes of A connected to one of B.
My exact problem is this, suppose I have 2 nodes a1, a2 of type A connected to b1 via the relationship rel. I have node a3 of type A related to node b2. I want to find a node b3 which contains a1, a2 and a3 and then form a relationship between b3 and b2, b1 if they fulfill a property(b3.prop/b2.prop>x & b3.prop/b1.prop>x). Is it possible to write a query in cypher that handles multiple relationships like this?

Answer (score 1):

This may work for your scenario:

```
MATCH (b1:B), (b2:B)
WHERE b1.id = 123 AND b2.id = 456
MATCH (a1:A)-[:rel]->(b1)
MATCH (a1)-[:rel]->(y1:B)
WHERE y1 <> b1 AND y1 <> b2
WITH b2, COLLECT(DISTINCT a1) AS a1s, COLLECT(DISTINCT y1) AS otherBs
WITH b2, [b IN otherBs WHERE ALL(a IN a1s WHERE (a)-[:rel]->(b))] AS candidates
WHERE SIZE(candidates) > 0
MATCH (a2:A)-[:rel]->(b2)
WITH candidates, COLLECT(a2) AS a2s
UNWIND [c IN candidates WHERE ALL(a IN a2s WHERE (a)-[:rel]->(c))] AS b3
RETURN b3
```

This query assumes the `rel` relationship is directed from `A` to `B`, and it will *only* return a result if there are any appropriate `b3` nodes. It first creates a list of all the possible `B` `candidates` related to the `A` nodes related to `b1`. Then it whittles down the `candidates` list, keeping only the `B` nodes that are also related to the `A` nodes related to `b2`.

There are many nuances in this query. For example, this snippet would abort the query if **any** `A` node with a `rel` relationship to `b1` does not also have a `rel` relationship to some other `B` node (that is not the same as `b1` and `b2`):

```
MATCH (a1)-[:rel]->(b1)
MATCH (a1)-[:rel]->(y1:B)
WHERE y1 <> b1 AND y1 <> b2
```

Whereas the following refactoring of the above snippet would only abort the query if **all** `A` nodes with a `rel` relationship to `b1` do not also have a `rel` relationship to some other `B` node (that is not the same as `b1` and `b2`):

```
MATCH (y1:B)<-[:rel]-(a1)-[:rel]->(b1)
WHERE y1 <> b1 AND y1 <> b2
```

Comment: This would work for a specifc 2 B right? I was sort of looking for a way to do this with all the combinations of b1 and b2 and create a relationship between the b3 and b1, b2 if b3.property/b1.property>x and b3.property/b2.property>x. But then performing that for all combinations would be a cartesian product

Comment: You should have made that clear in your question. It is probably possible to remove the cartesian product, but will require a good bit of effort to rework the existing answer. Will have to see if I have the additional time.

Comment: Is there any other way I can model this graph to solve the problem? The problem is that all the B nodes in the graph are unique entities, so I don't know if it's possible to solve it without the cartesian product